# Reverse tree walk of hierarchical data

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

I know how to navigate a hierarchy with `connect by` like this:

```
SELECT RPAD ('*', 2 * LEVEL, '*') || ename ename, empno 
FROM scott.emp 
START WITH mgr IS NULL 
CONNECT BY PRIOR empno = mgr
```

Now I want to walk the tree backwards using recursive `with` clause but  I cannot figure out how to do so.

Please assist me.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want, but did you try CONNECT BY PRIOR mgr=empno, and probably change the start with expression on suitable?

Answer (score 0):

There are two tricky points about the recursive WITH syntax.

We define two queries, one as the the anchor (the START WITH value) with a UNION ALL on a second query which retrieves the children of the hierarchical.

The other problem is that we cannot use LEVEL to generate the padding in the CONNECT BY query (because we're not using CONNECT BY).  So we add another column to maintain a count of the levels as we navigate the tree.  Note that I have started with zero, so that the top of the hierarchy isn't padded with asterisks.

So, here is your query re-cast as a recursive WITH statement:

```
with e1 (ename, empno, lvl) 
        as ( select ename
                    , empno
                    , 0 as lvl
             from emp
             where mgr is null
             union all
             select  e2.ename 
                    , e2.empno 
                    , e1.lvl + 1
              from emp e2, e1
                where e2.mgr = e1.empno )
search depth first by empno set empno_order
select rpad ('*', 2 * e1.lvl, '*') || e1.ename ename
       , e1.empno
from e1
order by empno_order
;
```

The `search depth first` clause guarantees the result set shows all the children of a given node before showing the sibling node.  (`search breadth first` would list all the siblings then start on the next level of the hierarchy.)

Now, to do a reverse tree walk we need to start with employees who aren't managers.  Because we're checking for nulls we need to use NOT EXISTS rather than NOT IN.  Otherwise the query is pretty much the same; I chose to show MGR rather than EMPNO but you may prefer to revert.

```
with e1 (ename, mgr, lvl) 
        as ( select e.ename
                    , e.mgr
                    , 0 as lvl
             from emp e
             where not exists ( select null 
                                from emp x
                                where x.mgr = e.empno)
             union all
             select  e2.ename 
                    , e2.mgr 
                    , e1.lvl + 1
              from emp e2, e1
                where e2.empno = e1.mgr )
search depth first by mgr set mgr_order
select rpad ('*', 2 * e1.lvl, '*') || e1.ename ename
       , e1.mgr
from e1
order by mgr_order
;
```

Here is sample output from this query:

```
ENAME                                 MGR
------------------------------ ----------
ALLEN                                7698
**BLAKE                              7839
****KING
JAMES                                7698
**BLAKE                              7839
****KING
MARTIN                               7698
**BLAKE                              7839
****KING
TURNER                               7698
...
```